# ASP.Net MVC 3 project with Ninject and HierarchicalLifetimeManager?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container, ninject-2

First of all, dependency injection is relatively new to me. I did a first project using Unity.MVC3, and now I would like to switch to Ninject on a new project, since it seems to be the most popular dependency injector for .Net projects. So now, I am trying to use Ninject v2.2.1.4 with Ninject.MVC3 v2.2.2.0 in my project.

In my previous project where I was using Unity, I had something like the following code in my Bootstrapper class:

```
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();            
    container.RegisterType<IDatabaseFactory, DatabaseFactory>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    container.RegisterType<ILoggingService, LoggingService>();

    container.RegisterControllers();

    return container;
}
```

Now, I my new project, I replaced this with something like the following code in the NinjectMVC3 class (App_Start):

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ITestService>().To<TestService>();
    //This does not compile:
    //kernel.Bind<IDatabaseFactory>().To<DatabaseFactory>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    kernel.Bind<IDatabaseFactory>().To<DatabaseFactory>();
    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
    kernel.Bind<ILoggingService>().To<LoggingService>();
}
```

However, I don't know what I should do with the DatabaseFactory binding, since it normally requires the use of HierarchicalLifetimeManager. Can anyone tell me how to properly create the binding for DatabaseFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, add these references bu NuGet to be sure that you have a compatible set of packages.

Then, if you add the Ninject.Web.MVC it will setup the project initialization code for you through a power shell script.

And last make a BindModule class like this and add it to module in `CreateKernel` method that have been created in second step.

```
public class BindModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IControllerActivator>().To<CustomControllerActivator>().InRequestScope();
        this.Bind<MembaseClient>().ToMethod(context => new MembaseClient()).InSingletonScope();
        this.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
        this.Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(o => MyAutoMapper.sessionFactory).InSingletonScope();
        this.Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(o => MyAutoMapper.sessionFactory.OpenSession()).InRequestScope();
        }
  }
```

**Part of NinjectMVC3 class**

```
public static class NinjectMVC3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var modules = new NinjectModule[] { new BindModule() };
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);

        RegisterServices(kernel);

        return kernel;
    }
}
```

As you can see above Ninjet has built in functions to take care of different life cycles for each object.

Comment: Thanks for your code samples and explanations! To tell you the truth, I still have to learn a lot about ASP.Net MVC and all these patterns. I am using the latest packages from Nuget, so versions should be ok. Is there a difference between using your BindModule.Load override and using the RegisterServices() method provided in the NinjectMVC3 class provided by Ninject.MVC3 ? By the way, there is no Ninject.Web.MVC package for MVC3.

Comment: Also, I don't fully understand what HierarchicalLifetimeManager is. I took that from a sample project I looked at to learn about MVC. Could you tell me what it should be replaced with when using Ninject?

Comment: I think No there is no big difference except that It's more modular and if you have many project, they can have their own NinjectModule AFAIK, but to answer the second question, I can't know but it should have sth to do with lifetime management which you can see examples of them above like Singleton, InRequestScope, InThreadScope.

Comment: Thanks Jani for your help and explainations! I will try using .InRequestScope() with my DatabasFactory hoping it will work properly.

Comment: For `DatabaseFactory` It should be `InSingletonScope()` if it's sth like that `BuildSessionFactory` of `NHibernate` but whenever you create a new session which is sth that IUnitOfWork should have a reference to, it must be `InRequestScope`.

Comment: @Jani: Did you read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.hierarchicallifetimemanager%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)?  "HierarchicalLifetimeManager Class: A special lifetime manager which works like ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, except that in the presence of child containers, each child gets it's own instance of the object, instead of sharing one in the common parent."  So it's a singelton unless you create a child container then you get a new instance that is a singleton in the child container.

Comment: @Tuzo So it's not a must-have for a simple project with one container, in Ninject era there is some extensions like `NamedScope` and `ChildKernel` which can address the same.

Comment: @Jani: That's right -- if you have one container then it will be treated as a singleton.

Comment: I don't think my IUnitOfWork has a reference to the session. I structured my project as the guy did on this page: http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/06/developing-web-apps-using-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-and-ef-code-first-part-1.aspx, and I have the same UnitOfWork has described on that page. I like his project struture, but I am not sure his UnitOfWork implementation is good though. I still don't understand all these patterns, and  am simply using some bits blindly until I have time to do more reading on the subject. Based on this what would you use for my DatabaseFactory?

Comment: You should use the `InRequestScope` for `DatabaseFactory`, and for UnitOfWork take a look at this article http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html